# Why do I need to create a virtual environment for my public Django application?

Tags: python, django, unix, virtualenv, digital-ocean

I've been running my Django project (website) in my local virtual environment. However I now want to go live and make the website public - so I've created my remote server on Digital Ocean, and have been following it's tutorial on settings up Django. However I've reached this point in the tutorial where [it says to create a virtual environment](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04#create-a-python-virtual-environment-for-your-project). I thought virtual environments were only used for testing your application offline? Why do I need a virtual environment for my application running on a remote server?

Comment: If you want to run multiple apps with different requirements on the same server, how would you do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not really familiar with Digital Ocean, but creating a `virtualenv` should not be strictly required.

It is still a good idea and I'd recommend doing it though.

It will prevent packages required for your application that you install to your [virtual environment](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/#creating-virtual-environments) from messing up other Python applications requirements.

For example, let's say your application requires `coolpackage 0.9.12`, and another application requires `coolpackage 1.1.6`. If there are breaking changes going from `0.9.12` to `1.1.6`, installing `coolpackage 1.1.6` will break your first application.

Also, keep in mind that some functionality of your operating system might require specific versions of Python packages (which might even have been installed by some other means than `pip`) that you could break in this way.